# How to store data with variable number of attributes in android

Tags: android, database, architecture, attributes

I am making application to collect health logs for a research purpose. I wanted some architecture design advice.

My app requirement:

1. There would be various forms with numerous fields.
2. This data needs to be stored locally (next phase is to store it on server)
3. Also we could have new form as the user base increases
4. The user must also be able to update a previously entered log

Question

```
For eg : 
Form 1 : (Name  , Age, Sex ) 
Form 2 : (Name  , Age, college, height )
The actual form has many fields related to health information
```

Since the data I receive from the user would have varied fields as above, how do I Store the data of multiple forms into the database. Also I want to add the functionality to add new forms to the app, thus making a database table for ever form is not a good idea (in my opinion). I was thinking to store the data as a JSON string in to the data base with the associated form ID.

Comment: JSON is a good solution for this, but might not be very efficient -- however, if you're only just dealing with one person per form, this would probably not be difficult. Another advantage is that it's easily serializable, and you can just pass a JSON string from one Activity to the next (as well as save state). If you want a pure SQL implementation, you'd have a master table (master_id, name) and a detail table (master_id, field_name, value) containing field data.

Comment: Yea that was my thought behind using JSON, thanks for your comment. SQL will be very complicated for my requirement. Is there some other technique for such implementations ?

Comment: JSON or XML make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Store each field as its own column in the database, query the database for the appropriate fields to recreate the various forms.

Note - that changing the field value, changes the value for all forms, unless you specify different column names to save the data under for the different forms.

See [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) on creating an SQlite database to get started.

Option 2. Serialize a hashmap and store the map as a blob in the database.  Easy to add new fields without changing your database.  Downside: Can't query for individual characteristics (age, sex, etc).  When you retrieve info on a person, you retrieve all of it, and pick what you need.  (simpler, but less efficient / robust).

Comment: Options 1 isn't very good as suggested -- you could easily introduce a master-id into the PK to differentiate the which form the custom columns relate to; that would make that a usable solution.